# Как узнать размер массива переданного в функцию?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, ссылки

Необходимо определить размер массива, переданного в функцию. Пробовал вот так:

```
void foo(int* Array)
{
    const unsigned int SIZE = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(int);
}
```

но в `SIZE` сохраняется 1, независимо от размера массива. Можно, конечно, вместе с массивом передать в функцию и его размер, но может существует более изящное решение?

P.S.: Кстати, заметил нечто странное. Запускал эту программу через Visual Studio и Qt. В VS в `SIZE` сохраняется 1, а в Qt 2.

Comment: sizeof(Array) - размер указателя на int в данном случае.

Comment: При имеющейся сигнатуре размер массива Вы узнать не сможете.

Comment: А при чём тут C++? Размер массива в C++ узнать очень просто: методом `size()` (если это, скажем, `vector`) или аналогичным.

Comment: @PinkTux так вопрос про обычные массивы, не STL-контейнеры же. Хотя согласен, в С++ по возможности стоит отказываться от сишных массивов в пользу `vector, array` и прочего.

Comment: [Вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526433/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be/526447#526447) еще может помочь

Comment: Просто подумайте сами: как можно зная лишь адрес, определить длину данных, начинающихся с него. Это невозможно. Поэтому в сигнатуры функций, принимающих указатели, добавляют параметр длины данных. По поводу "PS", то в Qt просто другой размер указателя - 64-битный, либо на этапе оптимизации int заменяется short`ом

Comment: @0xFFh встречный вопрос: но ведь `delete [] ptr` как-то знает :)

Comment: @alexolut, кажется, это вопрос к менеджеру памяти на уровне ос, который знает обо всех аллокациях

Comment: А вообще, о том, сколько элементов удалить при вызове "delete[]...":
При выполнении «new Type[count]» программа выделяет памяти столько, чтобы в нее поместились не только объекты, но и беззнаковое целое, обозначающее число объектов. В начало выделенной области пишется это число, дальше размещаются объекты.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

У вас параметр функции `foo` объявлен как указатель типа `int *`

```
void foo(int* Array);
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Следовательно внутри функции выражение

```
sizeof(Array)/sizeof(int)
```

эквивалентно выражению

```
sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int)
```

Если, например, размер указателя, то есть типа  `int *`, равен 8 байтам, а размер типа `int` равен 4 байтам, то в итоге вы получите 2. Если же при этом размер типа `int` равен также 8 байтам (64-битовая ОС), то вы получите в итоге 1.

Но  даже если вы объявите эту функцию как

```
void foo(int Array[]);
```

или даже так

```
void foo(int Array[10]);
```

все равно параметр функции неявно преобразуется в указатель на элемент массива. То есть эти два объявления функции объявляют одну и ту же функцию и эквивалетны следующему объявлению

```
void foo(int* Array);
```

Так что внутри функции вы снова будете иметь дело с указателем.

Когда массив передается по значению, то вам следует также объявлять второй параметр, который задает размер массива.

Или массив должен иметь некоторый граничный элемент с уникальным значением, по которому можно определить число актуальных элементов, как это имеет место, например, со строками, когда строки завершаются нулем, то есть символом `'\0'`.

То есть в общем случае вам следует объявлять функцию как

```
void foo(int* Array, size_t n);
```

где `n` - это размер массива.

Другой подход - это объявлять параметр как ссылку на массив. В этом случае длина массива будет известна внутри функции. Например

```
void foo( int ( &Array )[10] )
{
    const size_t = sizeof( Array)/ sizeof( *Array );
}
```

Недостаток этого объявления состоит в том, что эта функция может иметь дело только с массивами, заданного в ее параметре размера.

Чтобы обойти это ограничение, вы можете объявить шаблонную функцию. Например,

```
template <size_t N>
void foo( int ( &Array )[N] )
{
    const size_t n = N;
}
```

В этом случае компилятор, используя шаблон, создаст столько функций, сколько массивов разной длины были использованы в качестве аргумента.

Answer (score -1):

Возможный вариант, это поиск NULL для подсчета содержимого строки.

```
#include <stdint.h> // SIZE_MAX
size_t size_content(char* buf,size_t max){
        if(buf[0]==NULL){
                return 0;
        }    
        size_t pos = 0;
        while(--max){
                if(buf[pos]==NULL){
                        return pos;
                }
                pos++;
        }
        return max;
}

int main(){
        char content[500]="{\"command\":6,\"mp3\":[1,2,3],\"delay_sound\":2000,\"name\":\"Jeka\",\"name\":\"Jeka\"}";
        int size = size_content(content,SIZE_MAX);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]