# Массив - неправильно работает генерация случайных чисел

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

У меня есть две функции одна случайным образом заполняет массив, а другая должна работать с этим заполненным массивом. Но почему-то записывается только одно значение.

```
int* array;
void randomValues()
{
   std::srand(time(0));
   size_t array_size = 1000;
   array = new int[array_size];
   for (int index = 0; index < array_size; ++index)
      array[index] = (rand() % 999 + 1);
}

void evenOROdd()
{
   int evenCount = 0;
   int oddCount = 0;
   size_t arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
   for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
   {
       if ((array[index] % 2) != 0)
          ++evenCount;
       else if ((array[index] % 2) == 0)
          ++oddCount;
   }
   std::cout << "Even- " << evenCount << "\n";
   std::cout << "Odd- " << oddCount << "\n";
 }
```

Вывод: Even- 0
Odd- 1

Comment: Типичная ошибка: `array` — это указатель, а значит `sizeof(array)` вернёт размер указателя, а не всего массива. На практике обычно `4` или `8`. [Пример](https://ideone.com/OURXS0)

Comment: @ wololo а как  правильно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578109/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: @ wololo я  вынесла size_t arraySize = 1000;

Comment: @Оксана Волинець: Раз вынесли - значит пользуйтесь этим `arraySize`. Вот и все.

Comment: @AnT да уже работает все)

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
```

У вас `array` - указатель на `int`, так что его размер - 4 (ну, или 8) байт. Зависит от разрядности приложения.

Вам бы

```
size_t array_size = 1000;
```

вынести глобально, как и `array`...

Comment: Лучше `size_t arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);`

Comment: @Yami, И чем же это лучше, если в данном конкретном случае `array` имеет тип `int *`?

Comment: @user206435 - Еще лучше не заниматься колхозингом и вспомнить про std::array