# error C2664 c++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++

Ошибка: error C2664: "size_t strlen(const char *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "std::string" в "const char *" Для выполнения данного преобразования нет доступного оператора преобразования, определенного пользователем, или вызов оператора невозможен
error C2664: "char *strcat(char *,const char *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "std::string" в "char *"
Для выполнения данного преобразования нет доступного оператора преобразования, определенного пользователем, или вызов оператора невозможен

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>   // для функций strcpy, strcat
#include <stdlib.h>   // для функции exit
using namespace std;

class String          
{
private:
    enum { SZ = 80 }; 
    char str[SZ];     
public:
    String()
    {
        strcpy_s(str, "");
    }
    String(char s[])
    {
        strcpy_s(str, s);
    }
    void display() const
    {
        cout << str;
    }
    String operator += (String ss) const
    {
        String temp;                 
        if (strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < SZ)
        {
            strcpy_s(temp.str, str);   // копируем содержимое первой строки
            strcat_s(temp.str, ss.str);// добавляем содержимое второй строки
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nПереполнение!";
            exit(1);
        }
        return temp;                 // возвращаем результат
    }
};

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");

    String s1 = "\nHappy New Year!  "; /* Ошибка: не существует подходящего конструктора для переобразования из "const char[19]" в "String" */
    String s2 = "Merry Christmas!";   
    String s3;                      
    s1.display();
    s2.display();
    s3.display();

    s3 = s1 += s2;

    s3.display();
    cout << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код компилируется (конечно, после убирания ненужных `_s`). Но текст ошибки, о которой пишете в вопросе не соответствует коду.

Comment: Этот код для примера взят. Вся загвоздка в том, что при инициализации в String. При любом расскладе пишет:  Ошибка: не существует подходящего конструктора для переобразования из "const char[]" в "String"

Comment: Ваш код нормально работает (если заменить strcpy_s на strcpy) - https://ideone.com/xZLFPZ Как мы можем вам помочь, если не в состоянии воспроизвести ошибку? Да и в вопросе вы заявляете одни ошибки, в коде - другие, а в результате нет никаких?...

Comment: Ошибка или предупреждение компилятора? Всё таки в качестве параметра конструктора лучше использовать `const char s[]`, а не `char s[]`. А вообще текст ошибок намекает, что вы где-то случайно написали `string` вместо `String`.

Comment: Всё заработала при const char s[ ]. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: почему вообще `char s[]` ??? строковые литералы всегда же `const char*` были

Comment: @vegorov, В своём комментарии я имел ввиду параметр функции, а именно конструктора. Запись `const char s[]` в параметре функции эквивалента записи `const char *s`. А строковый литерал (без префикса) имеет тип "массив из `n` элементов типа `const char`".

Comment: @wololo все эти char[] как параметры я только в университете видел, привык уже к char* и const char*. А const char s[] это прям полный эквивалент const char* без каких либо различий ? Под `массив из n элементов типа const char` имеется в виду `const char[]` или `const char*` или и то и то ? Ну нигде не пишут `const char[]`, везде пишут `const char*`. `const char s[]` может быть `nullptr` ?

Comment: @vegorov, `const char s[]` эквивалент `const char *s` только в параметре функции. Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578121/262953). Строковый литерал имеет тип `const char [n]`, где `n` — количество элементов в массиве. Как и любой массив, строковый литерал может легко преобразовываться в указатель на его первый элемент, т.е. в `const char *`. [Пример для размышления](https://ideone.com/UQclBv).

Comment: @vegorov, `const char s[]` в параметре функции лучше чем `char s[]` в том смысле, что в данном конкретном случае лучше сделать `s` указателем на константу. Я не имел в виду, что с точки зрения оформления кода запись `const char s[]` лучше, чем `const char *s`. Более того, второй вариант мне самому нравится больше.

Comment: @wololo ну как я понял такая запись (`const char *`)просто напоминает разработчику что внутри функции у него будет уже указатель, не зависимо от того отдал он внутрь `const char[]`  или `const char*`