# В функцию внутри конструктора переменные передаются в произвольном порядке

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, классы, указатели

Моя проблема в том, что, если писать передачу переменных объекту класса engine в том же порядке, в котором они указаны в конструкторе, они все равно передаются в произвольном (или нет) порядке. Как это исправить?:

```
    class engine{
private:
    int vid_topl; // вид топлива
    int o_stup[3]; // объем каждой ступени
  int s_stup[3]; // скорость ступени
  int t_stup[3]; // время работы ступени
public:
    engine(int vi, int ob[3], int sk[3], int vr[3]) // СТРОКА 1
    {
        vid_topl = vi; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    o_stup[i] = ob[i];
    s_stup[i] = sk[i];
    t_stup[i] = vr[i];
  }
    }
int get_topl() 
  {return vid_topl;}

int get_o_st(int i) 
  {return o_stup[i];}

int get_s_st(int i) 
  {return s_stup[i];}

int get_t_st(int i) 
  {return t_stup[i];}
.......
int i, v, o[3], s[3], t[3];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
{
  printf("Введите объем ступени %d: ", i + 1);
  scanf("%d", &o[i]); // объем
  printf("Введите конечную скорость ступени %d (в км/ч): ", i + 1);
  scanf("%d", &s[i]); // скорость
  printf("Введите время работы ступени %d (в секундах): ", i + 1);
  scanf("%d", &t[i]); // время
}
......
engine raketa(v, &o[3], &s[3], &t[3]);
```

Ввод такой:

```
Введите объем ступени 1: 100
Введите конечную скорость ступени 1 (в км/ч): 1000
Введите время работы ступени 1 (в секундах): 10
Введите объем ступени 2: 200
Введите конечную скорость ступени 2 (в км/ч): 2000
Введите время работы ступени 2 (в секундах): 10
Введите объем ступени 3: 300
Введите конечную скорость ступени 3 (в км/ч): 3000
Введите время работы ступени 3 (в секундах): 10
```

при проверке

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
printf("Объем %d: %d\n", i, raketa.get_o_st(i)); 
printf("Скорость %d: %d\n", i, raketa.get_s_st(i)); 
printf("Время %d: %d\n", i, raketa.get_t_st(i)); 
}
```

выдает

```
Вид топлива: 100
Объем 0: 100
Скорость 0: 100
Время 0: 1000
Объем 1: 3
Скорость 1: 200
Время 1: 2000
Объем 2: 0
Скорость 2: 300
Время 2: 3000
```

Comment: `&o[3]` передает указатель на элемент, сразу после последнего в массиве, а его разыменование ведет к неопределенном поведению.

Comment: Без амперсантов ошибка (среда сама посоветовала сделать так и ошибка пропала).. Как вы советуете исправить?

Comment: Судя по всему, написав `int ob[3]` в параметре функции, вы думаете, что переменная `ob` внутри функции-конструктора `engine` является массивом. Это не так. `ob` внутри конструктора `engine` имеет тип "указатель на `int`". Ваш конструктор ожидает получить в качестве аргументов указатели на первые элементы массивов. Делайте так: `engine raketa(v, &o[0], &s[0], &t[0]);`, или воспользуйтесь способностью массивов неявно преобразовываться в указатель на свой первый элемент: `engine raketa(v, o, s, t);`.

Comment: Также рекомендую внимательно прочитать ответы на следующий вопрос: "[Как узнать размер массива переданного в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578109/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что за ерунду вы передаете в конструктор?

```
engine raketa(v, &o[3], &s[3], &t[3]);
```

Вы же передаете *несуществующие* массивы - за концами реальных! Вот так вызывайте:

```
engine raketa(v, o, s, t);
```