# Не определяется длина вектора c++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, vector, char

Пытаюсь определить длину переданого в функцию вектора, но всегда длина определяется как 8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

class myString{
    private:
    vector<char> str;

    public:

    myString(const char x[]){
        vector<char> tempStr( x, x+sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x) );
        str = tempStr;
        
    };
    void print(){
        for (int i =0; i<str.size();i++){
            cout<<str[i];
        };
        cout<<""<<endl;
    };

    void find(const char c[]){
        vector<char> temp(c, c+sizeof(с)/sizeof(*с));
        cout<<temp.size()<<endl;
        
    };
};

int main()
{
    myString str1("dasdasda");
    str1.print();
    str1.find("asd");
    str1.find("dasda");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать размер массива переданного в функцию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578109/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 6):

[Устало вздохнув, монотонным голосом] как известно при передаче в функцию массива (почему вы его называете вектором?!) он преобразуется в указатель, так что

```
sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)
```

есть

```
sizeof(char*)/sizeof(char)
```

или для 64-разрядного приложения, 8/1 = 8.

Что спросили - то компилятор и ответил.

Если уж вы передаете строки, логичнее было бы работать со строками. Но, в конце концов, можно и

```
myString(const char x[]):str(x,x+strlen(x)+1){}
```

+1 - на тот случай, если вам и нулевой завершающий символ нужен.

Но лучше бы вам брать строку `string`, а не `vector<char>` - куда более естественно и удобно.