# Как узнать размер массива с доступом через указатель с помощью std::size()? И можно ли?

Tags: c++

Изучаю c++.
Есть простейший код:

```
auto p10 {new int[5]};
```

Пытаюсь узнать его размер через std::size(), но никак не получается.

Comment: Потому что это не массив, а всего лишь указатель... Пользуйтесь `vector` или `array`, например...
А вообще этот вопрос тут задавался, наверное, с сотню раз. Вот, например — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/578109/195342