# Хочу вернуть массив из функции, но вылетает ошибка, что делать? C++

Tags: c++

Хотел сделать функцию, которая будет создавать массив и возвращать его в main, но что то пошло не так. Объясните где я не правильно сделал.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int create_board () {
    int board[10];
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
        board[i] = i;
    }
    return board;
}

int main () {
    int board = create_board();
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
        cout >> board[i] << " ";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Во-первых**, в функции `create_board` переменная `board` у вас имеет тип `int [10]` (т.е. массив из `10` значений типа `int`). А Вы пытаетесь присвоить это значение переменной типа `int` вот здесь:

```cpp
int board = create_board();
```

что даёт ошибку несоответствия типов. Нужно заменить на:

```cpp
int* board = create_board(); // Звёздочка после int
```

и объявление функции, соответственно, поменять на

```cpp
int* create_board () //Массив может неявно приводиться к указателю на первый элемент
```

**Во-вторых**, когда Вы делаете вот так:

```cpp
int board[10];
```

память под массив выделяется в стеке ([читайте подробности тут](https://ravesli.com/urok-105-stek-i-kucha/)). А вся память, выделенная в стеке, очищается, при выходе соответствующей переменной из [области видимости](https://ravesli.com/urok-48-lokalnye-peremennye-oblast-vidimosti-i-vremya-zhizni/). Вкратце, как только выполнение Вашего кода доходит до фигурной скобки, завершающей функцию `create_board`, память массива `board` очищается и, следовательно, все значения в нём становятся недоступны. Отсюда и ошибка.

Теперь о том, что с этим делать. Если уж со стеком всё так плохо, нужно выделить память под массив в куче (в динамической памяти), заменив это:

```cpp
int board[10];
```

на вот это:

```cpp
int* board = new int[10];
```

**Внимание, не забудьте очистить выделенную память, когда массив станет Вам не нужен, таким образом:**

```cpp
int* board = create_board(); // Создаёте массив
//... Используйте массив, как хотите
delete[] board; // Когда стал не нужен, чистите память
```

**В-третьих**, ну в конце-то концов, в какую сторону ставится знак помещения в поток после `cout`? В эту `<<`! А у Вас сначала в одну, потом в другую...

P.S. В блокноте Вы свой код пишете чтоли... IDE же большинство этих ошибок Вам сама рассказать должна была.

Comment: int* это тип переменной, обозначающий массив?

Comment: @Dariuz, не только массив. Это просто указатель на тип `int`. В случае с массивом берётся указатель на его первый элемент.

Answer (score 2):

Ты создал временный обьект на стеке, и вернул его. Компилятор должен был сказать что варнинг! выходя из стека ф-ии твой массив разрушается . Попробуй выделить массив динамически.
Во вторых ты возвращал число , а не массив

Попробуй:

```
int* create_board () {
    int* board = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
        board[i] = i;
    }
    return board;
}
```

[Как передать массив в функцию и вернуть его?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526433/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Answer (score 2):

Массив нельзя вернуть из функции напрямую, но есть несколько обходных вариантов.

Про `new` и `delete` подсказали в соседних ответах, но [это подходит только для практики](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/2752075). В реальной жизни возвращают контейнер: [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) или [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

std::array<int, 10> create_board()
{
    std::array<int, 10> board;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        board[i] = i;
    return board;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> board = create_board();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << board[i] << " ";
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> create_board()
{
    std::vector<int> board;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        board.push_back(i);
    return board;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> board = create_board();
    for (int x : board)
        std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Есть еще один вариант: создавать массив снаружи функции, передавать его как параметр, и в функции заполнять:

```
#include <iostream>

void create_board(int *board)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        board[i] = i;
}

int main()
{
    int board[10];
    create_board(board);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << board[i] << " ";
}
```